# Conversion between javacv and opencv to get mean and stdDev from a Mat

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

i can successfully access the value of mean and stdDev using opencv in eclipse. But i am fail to do so with javacv in Android. There are two main problems. First, no MatODouble is supported in javacv. Second, no "get" function  can be called. Anyone here know how to translate these code for javacv.

Please give me a helping hand, i need you all indeed......

```
MatOfDouble mu = new MatOfDouble();
MatOfDouble sigma = new MatOfDouble();
Core.meanStdDev( detected_edges, mu, sigma);
double m = mu.get(0,0)[0];
double d = sigma.get(0,0)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example may helps:
[ColorCalibrator.java](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/ColorCalibrator.java)

```
CvMat b = CvMat.create(referenceColors.length*3, 1);

...

CvScalar mean = new CvScalar(), stddev = new CvScalar();
cvAvgSdv(b, mean, stddev, null);
```

After that `mean` and `stddev` can be used as a 4-element vector (i.e. `stddev.val(0)`).

---

**Update #1** on how to create `CvMat` from `BufferedImage`:

```
// To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, or vice versa, we can chain calls to
// Java2DFrameConverter and OpenCVFrameConverter, one after the other.
Java2DFrameConverter cvt1 = new Java2DFrameConverter();
OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage cvt2 = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();

BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
IplImage image1 = cvt2.convert(cvt1.convert(img));

CvMat image2 = image1.asCvMat();
```

Comment: I am really appreciate your help, since javacv learner is lack of support here...

Comment: Do you know how to read image into the Format CvMat? Or convert a Mat  to a CvMat format.  I have look arround the internet, no soloution for Javacv ( Version: bytedeco ) . Hope somebody can help TT